# Justify in Fixed modal windows css

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have modal windows with the same width+height, and same classes. In first case i have 3 columns (fixed height and float left styles), in second - 2 columns. How can I get it more beatiful, by that this colums justify?

```
#instruments-modal .panel, #specialities-modal .panel {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

#instruments-modal .panel label, #specialities-modal .panel label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

### Images:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: thanks i'll used juery for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of using `width:auto`, give percentage widths based on the modal being displayed like this:

```
#instruments-modal .panel {width:33.33%;}
#specialities-modal .panel {width:50%;}
#instruments-modal .panel, #specialities-modal .panel {float: left;}
```